# Why doesn't `git -C` work from Python in a post receive hook?

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

Try this:

```
mkdir /tmp/one
cd /tmp/one
git init
echo -e "#!/usr/bin/env python3\nimport os\nos.system('git -C /tmp/one show')" > /tmp/one/.git/hooks/post-receive
chmod +x /tmp/one/.git/hooks/post-receive
touch test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
cd /tmp/
git clone one two
cd two
git checkout -b test
echo "Why doesn't this work?" >> test.txt
git add test.txt
git commit -m "testing"
git push -u origin test
```

And observe the very confusing message:

```
remote: fatal: Not a git repository: '.'
```

What?

Seriously, what the actual heck? Why is this completely broken? I can go to a literal folder that is not a git repository (`cd / && git -C /tmp/one/show`) and it works fine. Why doesn't this command work?

It also doesn't work if I do `os.chdir('/tmp/one')`. I cannot make the post-receive hook actually figure out what the heck is going on. It's more than happy to run some other commands, like `git merge`, but it will not understand git show, git status, or more importantly for me, `git -C /tmp/one checkout master`. I've also tried with just a bare

```
#!/bin/sh
git -C /tmp/one status
```

And it gives me the same error mesage - `not a git repostiory: '.'`

Any clue what in the world is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is that commands run from a Git hook are run with various environment variables set.  The one that's hitting you is `$GIT_DIR`, but there could be others (e.g., `$GIT_WORK_TREE`, `$GIT_INDEX_FILE`, and so on).

They're set *correctly* for dealing with the repository you're in *at the time the hook runs*.  But you don't want this hook to deal with this repository.  You want this hook to `chdir` somewhere else and deal with some *other* repository.  At that point, you should clean out the unwanted environment variables, or override them with correct settings for *that* repository.

In short, add:

```
unset GIT_DIR
```

(for sh/bash/etc), or in Python:

```
del os.environ['GIT_DIR']
```

(note that the Python version only works when it's actually set), or use the `env` argument when using `subprocess`, etc.

Comment: So git overrides `-C` and the current directory with `GIT_DIR`? That seems silly! But removing it works!

Comment: It doesn't overrides. It executes it (by doing `cd /tmp/one`) but then it doesn't use the current directory as the repository because `$GIT_DIR` and `$GIT_WORK_TREE` point to different directories. Unsetting these variables make git to use the current directory which is `/tmp/one`.